# regex search with renumbering in replace

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with anywhere between a dozen and hundreds of matches on the search

```
 /playOrder="(\d+)"/
```

These are in the index file of an ePub ebook, in case anyone is wondering.

Is it possible to have a perl regex replace what finds all these, and "magically" renumber them all to a sequence, starting from 1?

Comment: `perl -pe 's/playOrder="\K\d+"/++$i . q(")/ge' infile > outfile`

Comment: @TLP, Thanks. Post as a n answer please, so I can approve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting comment as answer, as requested by OP:

```
perl -pe 's/playOrder="\K\d+"/++$i . q(")/ge' infile > outfile
```

This one-liner is using a replacement field which is created by evaluation, creating a sequence like `1"`, `2"`...

Further optimization can be made if using a lookahead assertion instead of inserting a new double quote `"`:

```
perl -pe 's/playOrder="\K\d+(?=")/++$i/ge' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver with this one. Doing 163 replacements by hand would have driven me up the walls. :P